# Convert image_ptr to Mat container

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I am trying to convert the image_ptr received from the network into a Mat container of OpenCV.
The image resolution is 1920x1080
If we put 1080, 1920 in the first and second parameters,
It stops when a segment fault occurs.

How should we approach to solving the problem?

```
int ConvertToCVmat(unsigned char* pImage, int ImageSize)
{
    std::cout << "pImage : " << pImage << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ImageSize : " << ImageSize << std::endl;

    fprintf(stderr, "%s=%d, %s\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, "");

    using namespace cv;

    int result = 0;

    // Mat cvimg = cv::Mat(480, 720, CV_8UC1, pImage);
    Mat wrapped(1080, 1920, CV_8UC3, (unsigned char*)pImage, Mat::AUTO_STEP);

    if (wrapped.empty())
    {
        std::cerr << "Image load failed!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("current Image");

    imshow("current Image", wrapped);

    waitKey(0);

    return result;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: is it a single channel image? Use CV_8UC1

Comment: hello, @Miki
no It is a RGB jpeg image.
Thank you.